# How to apply debouncer on change function jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onchange

How would one apply debouncer on this jQuery function. So far it makes no call.

```
 $('.make-ajax-call-js').on($.debounce('change', function (e) {
//whatever ajax call
}));
```

I have debouncer script included in my js files.

Comment: Did you check the documentation of the plugin?

Comment: Why is this tagged with `ajax`? There's no AJAX...

Comment: Using jQuery throttle / debounce, you can pass a delay and function to $. debounce to get a new function, that when called repetitively, executes the original function just once per "bunch" of calls. This can be especially useful for rate limiting execution of handlers on events that will trigger AJAX requests.  @andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$('.make-ajax-call-js').change($.debounce(1000, function(e) {
    console.log("It works!");
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, you will have to pass in the debouncing function as a parameter to the jquery click event along with the debounce time

```js
$('.make-ajax-call-js').click($.debounce(250, function(e) {
    //whatever ajax call
}));
```